# Variable name is undefined in ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to write a role playbook that completes some of its tasks on the machine that the playbook is running on. I have defined the variable by using bash script to generate the vars files in vars folder of the role. After that, the next task will deploy multiple network with defined vars from bash script, but I am getting this error:

> fatal [target node]: FAILED! => { msg": "'vars_t0' is undefined}

This is my playbook:

```
    - name: Running Script
      script: generate_var.sh 2
      register: result


    - name: Modify Tier0
      vmware.ansible_for_nsxt.nsxt_policy_tier0:
        hostname: "********"
        username: "admin"
        password: "********"
        validate_certs: False
        state: present
        display_name: "{{ item.t0_name }}"
        locale_services:
          - state: present
            edge_cluster_info:
              edge_cluster_display_name: "*******"
            preferred_edge_nodes_info:
              - edge_cluster_display_name: "********"
                edge_node_display_name: "*********"
      with_items: "{{ var_t0 }}"
```

This is the vars file, which is generated from task bashscript:

```
vars_t0:
  - t0_name: T0_GW_01
  - t0_name: T0_GW_02
```

Comment: Do you intend for your script to do more than generate variables of maping `t0_name: T0_GW_{1..n}`? If not than it would be easier to generate those mappings within ansible and passing that variable

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because while you're running creating the variable file, Ansible isn't loading it.

If all your doing is creating a list of variables I suggest you try `with_sequence` which does all of the work your script is doing within Ansible.

#### with_sequence

`with_sequence` using the following variables

1. `start` what to start iterating from
2. `end` what the last value will be
3. `format` formatting of the resulting number

within `format` i'm concatenating "T0_GW_" with the resulting number padded by 2 zeros.
Example Solution

```yaml
---
- name: Modify Tier0
  vmware.ansible_for_nsxt.nsxt_policy_tier0:
    hostname: "********"
    username: "admin"
    password: "********"
    validate_certs: False
    state: present
    display_name: "{{item}}"
    locale_services:
      - state: present
        edge_cluster_info:
          edge_cluster_display_name: "*******"
        preferred_edge_nodes_info:
          - edge_cluster_display_name: "********"
            edge_node_display_name: "*********"
  with_sequence: start=1 end=2 format=T0_GW_%02d
```

more on sequence https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/sequence_lookup.html#parameter-format